# Move y axis labels to left side of heatmap.2

Tags: axis, heatmap, margins

I would like to move the y-axis labels to the left side of heatmap.2. (This is similar, but not the same, as the question regarding moving the axis on heatmap) 
 While I am able to move the axis by editing line 290 of the heatmap.2 function, it the values then overwrite the actual heatmap.

```
if (is.null(srtRow) && is.null(colRow)) {
    axis(4, iy, labels = labRow, las = 2, line = -0.5 + offsetRow, 
         tick = 0, cex.axis = cexRow, hadj = adjRow[1], padj = adjRow[2])
  }

  else {

    if (is.null(srtRow) || is.numeric(srtRow)) {

      xpd.orig <- par("xpd")

      par(xpd = NA)
      ypos <- axis(4, iy, labels = rep("", nr), las = 2, #change
                   line = -0.5, tick = 0)
      text(x = par("usr")[2] + (1 + offsetRow) * strwidth("M"), 
           y = ypos, labels = labRow, adj = adjRow, cex = cexRow, 
           srt = srtRow, col = colRow)
      par(xpd = xpd.orig)
    }
```

I tried moving the location of the heatmap.2 by mucking about with the lwid and lhei options, but the overwrite problem persisted.

Thank you
Eric

Comment: Did you try changing the first argument of axis from 4 to 2?